# Wrong script url being requested

Tags: c#, http, razor, nancy, owin

I'm running Nancy using Self Hosting / OWIN and the Razor view engine

Specifically:

```
Nancy 0.21.1
Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor 0.21.1
Microsoft Owin.SelfHost 2.0.1
```

I have a html page with the following script reference

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

If i make the following request (note the trailing slash)

```
http://localhost:3456/log/
```

The html page is correctly returned and the following script request is made

```
http://localhost:3456/log/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

This is the correct behavior.

If i then make this request (note there is no trailing slash)

```
http://localhost:3456/log
```

The html page is correctly returned however a different script request is made.

```
http://localhost:3456/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

This fails because it is the wrong URL. The script needs to be under /log

Nancy allows you to change the URL before it is handled, so I've tried adding the trailing slash if it is missing but this doesn't change anything (seems like a hack anyway)

Preferably I'd like to get it working without having to worry about the trailing slash. Failing that I guess I'd need a way to modify the initial response so the http referrer header is returned with the trailing slash? It's not obvious how to do this though.

N.B. My setup isn't a standard Nancy one. There's some custom static content conventions and view location conventions being used to get it to work how I want it to. Everything works correctly except when the trailing slash is missing.

This thread seems to talk about the same problem but for ASP.NET

http://forums.asp.net/t/1897093.aspx?Trailing+Slash+Nightmare

## UPDATE 1

As suggested by @AndreD, using

```
/log/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

Does work for both cases however "log" is a variable prefix and can not be hard-coded. A html helper may be an option and this is what I'm currently looking at the solve the problem

Comment: What version of Nancy are you using? what owin server are you using(katana,IIS,selfhost)? I have this kind of problem when i used kayak,but in this moment kayak it's not compatible with the current OWIN version.

Comment: I'm using self host. I've added some details to the top of the question

Comment: I don't know the Nancy framework or OWIN, so I'm posting a comment instead of an answer, but I suspect this problem has to do with relative URLs. The relative URL used in src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" refers to a completely different resource if the base path is /log or /log/.

Comment: If you're using document-relative URLs, you might try root-relative URLs instead. In other words, reference "/log/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" instead of "Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"

Comment: Thanks @AndreD. Using /log/Scripts/... does work however the problem I have with this is that "log" is a defined variable, so I don't want to have it hard-coded. I may see if I can write a helper that generates the correct urls

Comment: what viewengine are you using? in my case when i want to add a link or reference of an script in razor i use the @Url.Content("~/Content/js/libs/jquery.min.js") and works, maybe you can add a concatenation with your variable that have the "log" value.

Comment: I'm using razor, i've updated the question. I'll have a look at the helper, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was to create a helper which creates the correct script path

```
/log/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

Helper class extensions

```
*SomeNamespace*

public static class UrlHelpers
{
  public static string Script<TModel>(this Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.UrlHelpers<TModel> Self,     string Script)
  {
    var rootPath = Self.RenderContext.Context.Request.Path.TrimEnd('/');
    var scriptPath = string.Format("{0}/Scripts/{1}", rootPath, Script);
    return scriptPath;
   }
}
```

View:

```
@using SomeNamespace
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase
  ...
  ...

  <script src=@Url.Script("jquery-1.6.4.min.js")></script>
  <script src=@Url.Script("jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js")></script>
```